# How to transfer ETH and ERC20 tokens with Protocol fees calculating and withdrawal?

Tags: erc-20, transfer, transferfrom

Good afternoon. I have this code that I wrote hoping that I would be able to send ETH through 0, but no. I understand that I need to send it via msg.value but then I don’t understand how I can code it correctly so that the user can send ETH and allow 2 ERC20 tokens - and that he would have a fixed commission of 0.005 ETH + 1% of all tokens, including ether if he sends it?

```
function batchTransfer(
        address[] memory tokenAddresses,
        uint256[] memory amounts,
        address receiver
    ) public payable whenNotPaused {
        require(!isPausedInCore(), "BatchTransfer is paused in Core");
        require(msg.value == fixedFeesETH, "Incorrect ETH fee amount");

        for (uint256 i = 0; i < tokenAddresses.length; i++) {
            uint256 commissionAmount;
            uint256 transferAmount;

            if (tokenAddresses[i] == address(0)) { 

                commissionAmount = amounts[i].mul(feesRatePercent).div(100);
                transferAmount = amounts[i].sub(commissionAmount);

                // Проверяем, что ETH достаточно для перевода с учетом комиссии
                payable(receiver).transfer(transferAmount);
                
            } else { // ERC20 token transfer
                IERC20 token = IERC20(tokenAddresses[i]);
                commissionAmount = amounts[i].mul(feesRatePercent).div(100);
                transferAmount = amounts[i].sub(commissionAmount);
                // Переводим ERC20 токены на адрес получателя
                require(token.transferFrom(msg.sender, receiver, transferAmount), "Token transfer failed");
                // Переводим комиссию в токенах на адрес кошелька комиссий
                require(token.transferFrom(msg.sender, coreContract.getSafeWallet(), commissionAmount), "Commission transfer failed");
            }
        }

        // Переводим фиксированную комиссию в ETH на адрес кошелька комиссий
        payable(coreContract.getSafeWallet()).transfer(msg.value);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I’m find a solution

```
function batchTransfer(
        address[] memory tokenAddresses,
        uint256[] memory amounts,
        address receiver
    ) public payable whenNotPaused {
        require(!isPausedInCore(), 'BatchTransfer is Paused in Core');
        require(msg.value >= fixedFeesETH, 'Insufficient ETH for fixed fees');

        uint256 totalCommissionETH = fixedFeesETH; // Фиксированная комиссия в ETH

        for (uint256 i = 0; i < tokenAddresses.length; i++) {
            uint256 feesAmount = amounts[i].mul(feesRatePercent).div(100);
            uint256 toReceiverAmount = amounts[i].sub(feesAmount);

            IERC20 token = IERC20(tokenAddresses[i]);
            require(token.transferFrom(msg.sender, receiver, toReceiverAmount), 'Tokens transfer failed');
            require(token.transferFrom(msg.sender, coreContract.getSafeWallet(), feesAmount), 'Fees Transfer Failed');
        }

        uint256 excessETH = msg.value.sub(fixedFeesETH);
        if (excessETH > 0) {
            uint256 percentFees = excessETH.mul(feesRatePercent).div(100);
            uint256 toTransfer = excessETH.sub(percentFees);

            payable(receiver).transfer(toTransfer);
            totalCommissionETH = totalCommissionETH.add(percentFees);
        }

        payable(coreContract.getSafeWallet()).transfer(totalCommissionETH);
    }
```